# Dynamic Link Change

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I am looking for a solution to help me with dynamic links.

Let's say I have a basic link like so:

```
<a href="~/Test/Test.pdf" target="_blank">Test Dynamic Links</a>
```

If I have a button or input rather, to let a user replace that link with another link how would I go about doing so?

Example:

A user wants to change the link above to:

```
<a href="~/Test2/Test2.pdf" target="_blank">Test Dynamic Links</a>
```

So, the user would click the `<input type="file" />` button.. browse to `~/Test2/Test2.pdf` and click Open.  How would I change the `href` value of the previous link to the new one, using the File Explorer?

Keeping in mind that the text of the link does not change.

Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @BvilleKid none of the answers here addresses your issue? You need to atleast acknowledge their efforts and time and let them know if their answer works for you or not.. I think that's a due respect you can give ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, the user would click the  button.. browse to ~/Test2/Test2.pdf and click Open. How would I change the href value of the previous link to the new one, using the File Explorer?

Answer is **you cannot**. You cannot read the client machine path using JavaScript. This is a security restriction followed by all browsers.

Even if you fetch the file path using `$('#yourFileInput').val()`  it gives you fake path to keep user info secured.

You can get the `filename` however. If that is of any use to you.

Answer (score 2):

```js
  $(".upload").change(function() {
    $(this).prev('a').attr('href',$(this).val());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="~/Test/Test.pdf" target="_blank">Test Dynamic Links</a>
<input type="file" class="upload">
```

So, you will have to tweak selectors (probably), but this is basic example...

Answer (score 0):

You tagged your post with jQuery, so here's how to change an attribute using jQuery:

HTML:

```
<a class="testlink" href="~/Test/Test.pdf" target="_blank">Test Dynamic Links</a>
```

JS:

```
var link = "~/Test2/Test2.pdf"; //set var to new href
$('.testlink').attr('href', link); //set link href to var
```